# How to compute delta coefficients in mathematica

Tags: signal-processing

I want to get delta coefficients calculated. The definition can be found [here](http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/). However, I don't know what to do with the minus indices. I have tried computing it in a slightly different way, namely:

```
delta[data_] :=
Block[
    {
        nData = Most[Prepend[data, 0]],
        l = Length[data],
        sum
    },

    N[Divide[
        Plus @@ Times[data - nData, Range[l]],
        Plus @@ (data ^ 2)
    ]]
]
```

My question is, whether there's other, easier way, of computing the delta coefficients?

Comment: Would you please also provide an example dataset `data`. I presume that `data` is a vector of numbers but who knows? (Right, it is _only_ you.)

Comment: Hi, data is a vector of numbers. E.g. data ={0.0995563,-0.002073,-0.0541243,0.0662532,0.153794,0.0654639,0.158421,0.0362688,0.113608,0.156917,0.114574,0.0606766,0.0106301}

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following; it is concise, accurate, and fast.

```
delta1[data_] := With[{a = Developer`ToPackedArray[N[data]]},
  ListConvolve[{1., -1.}, a, 1, 0.].Range[N[Length[a]]]/Total[a^2]
  ]

n = 10^5;
data = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, n];
r1 = delta[data]; // RepeatedTiming // First
r2 = delta1[data]; // RepeatedTiming // First
Max[Abs[r1 - r2]]
```

> 0.0887
>
> 0.0016
>
> 2.77556*10^-15

A general suggestion for performance: Better apply `N` *before* any actual computations are performed. (This rule holds only as long as the computations are free of any issues about severe precision loss.)

Should you decide to use cyclic differences, then replace

```
ListConvolve[{1., -1.}, a, 1, 0.]
```

by

```
ListConvolve[{1., -1.}, a, 1]
```